# Entity Framework 6 Trigger values not in object after SaveChanges()

Tags: triggers, entity-framework-6

How can I ensure that EF 6 retrieves the changes to a record that are made after a trigger executes?

My issue is that I have a trigger on my table that generates column values after insert.  When I add my new object and call SaveChanges(), I want to turn around and get that object back out with the updated values.  I've found some similar questions here, but they are old and suggest using things like context.Refresh() that do not exist now.  In one case there was a suggestion to use:

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
```

This hasn't helped either.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I found a hack to get what I need, but it involves creating a new instance of the context and then doing my ef query.  It's not ideal, if anyone can help with a more appropriate solution I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I think you should mark the column as `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed`, but you can only do this if you don't set its value in code.